# Operator norm on $L_2$: Possible quick methods

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there a quick way to show the compactness and compute the operator norm of 
$$Tf(x) = \int_\Omega K(x,y)f(y)dy $$
$T:L_2(\Omega)\rightarrow L_2(\Omega)$? ($K\in C(cl(\Omega)\times cl(\Omega))$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compactness is obtained if 
\begin{align*}
\iint_{\Omega\times\Omega}|K(x,y)|^{2}dx\times dy<\infty,
\end{align*}
this is known as Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator, which is compact.

For the norm of the operator, it seems to me that there is no general method for that.

Comment: Thank you. Is that a sufficient condition to check for compactness of an operator? Also, do you have a reference so I can look up the operator norm?

Comment: Yes, sufficient, but not necessary. For reference, see Joachim Weidmann, *Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces*, but I don't think there is a universal method for calculating the operator norm.

Comment: Do you know which chapter by any chance?

Comment: Page 139 of the book, Chapter 6.

Comment: Why is $\sum_n\|Te_n\|^2=\|T\|^2$?

Comment: I didn't mean that, neither does the book.

Comment: I'm looking at Theorem 6.11.

Comment: In some sense that is Parseval equality in $L^{2}$ with respect to that basis.